# Clustering order does not work with compound partition key

Tags: sorting, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, compound-key

With the following table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE device_by_create_date (
    year int,
    comm_nr text,
    created_at timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY ((year, comm_nr), created_at)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (created_at DESC)
```

`Comm_nr` is a unique identifier.

I would expect to see data ordered by `created_at` column, which is not the case when I add data.

**Example entries:**

[image]

**Table CQL:**

[image]

How can I issue `select * from table;` queries, which return data ordered by the `created_at` row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TLDR**: You need to create a new table.

Your partition key is `(year, comm_nr)`.  You're created_at key is ordered but it is ordered WITHIN that partition key.  A query where `SELECT * FROM table WHERE year=x AND comm_nr=y;` will be ordered by created_at.

Additionally if instead of `(year, comm_nr), created_at` your key was instead `year, comm_r, created_at` even if your create table syntax only specifiied created_at as the having a clustering order, it would be created as `WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (comm_nr DESC, created_at DESC)`.  Data is sorted within SSTables by key from left to right.

The way to do this in true nosql fashion is to create a separate table where your key is instead `year, created_at, comm_nr`.  You would write to both on user creation, but if you needed the answer for who created their account first you would instead query the new table.

Comment: Thank you! Lets say I want to display all devices from 2017 and 2018. In this case I would issue 2 queries - what about paging the result? PagingState is only available per ResultSet. Custom implentation?

Comment: You should be able to get away with `SELECT * FROM table WHERE year IN (2017, 2018) ...` This will be "1 query" from the application side and should be ordered in that fashion.

Understand though that the 1 query will hit `<Consistency>*<Number of Partition Keys>` nodes when it tries to achieve consistency.  So your cluster will be doing more work than when on a regular query.

Comment: Thats right, but wasnt the usage of IN discouraged?

Comment: Alternatively, you could instead do the coordination(custom implementation) of that sorting in the application layer as TYPICALLY the application layer will scale better than the Data layer.  `IN` is discouraged because of that scaling issue above.   You're putting more work on the coordinator node (memory pressure and network) and you're hitting more of the cluster with one query.